# How to modify the values of designate elements in xml file with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, xml

There is a xml file like below:

```
<hh>
  <aa>
    <cc>
      <ee>
        <Name>John</Name>
      </ee>
    <cc>
      <ee>
        <Name>David</Name>
      </ee>
  </aa>
  <bb>
    <dd>
      <Name>John</Name>
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <Name>David</Name>
    </dd>
  </bb>
</hh>
```

I'm trying to modify the name:
"John --> Rose", and "David --> Gina"

So I write the code as below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob


for file in glob.glob("ff/*.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    a01 = "aa/cc[1]/ee"
    a02 = "bb/dd[1]"
    b01 = "aa/cc[2]/ee"
    b02 = "bb/dd[2]"

    apaths = [a01, a02]
    bpaths = [b01, b02]

    for i in apaths:
        aa = root.findall(apaths)
        aa.text = "Rose"

    tree.write(file)

    for i in bpaths:
        bb = root.findall(bpaths)
        bb.text = "Gina"

    tree.write(file)
```

But it response "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". Could someone help me to correct my code?
Many thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer. It should work for you. Let me know what is missing?

Comment: I have added new code. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Element.findall with a list argument, instead do:

```
for i in apaths:
        aa = root.findall(i)
        aa[0].text = "Rose"
```

and

```
 for i in bpaths:
        bb = root.findall(i)
        bb[0].text = "Gina"
```

Comment: After I modify the code, it stop at the line "aa.text = "Rose"", and response the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'".

Comment: Try setting: 
   `a01 = "aa/cc[1]/ee[1]"
    a02 = "bb/dd[1]"
    b01 = "aa/cc[2]/ee[1]"
    b02 = "bb/dd[2]"`

Comment: It still stop at the same line and response the same message. Is it the issue of array?

Comment: Try printing aa after finall and see what it is set to.

Comment: Print result is like: "[<Element 'ee' at 0x00000000029FFCC8>]", is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete working code

**Updated** as per new requirements

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

for file in glob.glob("ff/*.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for name in root.findall('.//aa//Name'):
        name.text = 'Rose'

    for name in root.findall('.//bb//Name'):
        name.text = 'Gina'

    tree.write(file)
```

**Updated Code** to operate on all xml files in a directory

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

name_map = {
    'John': 'Rose',
    'David': 'Gina',
}

for file in glob.glob("ff/*.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for name in root.findall('.//Name'):
        new_name = name_map.get(name.text)
        if new_name:
            name.text = new_name

    tree.write(file)
```

## Code to rename in an xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_str = '''
<hh>
  <aa>
    <cc>
      <ee>
        <Name>John</Name>
      </ee>
    </cc>
      <ee>
        <Name>David</Name>
      </ee>
  </aa>
  <bb>
    <dd>
      <Name>John</Name>
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <Name>David</Name>
    </dd>
  </bb>
</hh>
'''


name_map = {
    'John': 'Rose',
    'David': 'Gina',
}

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
print(ET.tostring(xml))

for name in xml.findall('.//Name'):
    new_name = name_map.get(name.text)
    if new_name:
        name.text = new_name

print(ET.tostring(xml))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sometimes the name is not "John" or "David" in my xml file, maybe "Anderson" or "Jack". But I still need to modify the names to "Rose" and "Gina" in my xml file, so I can't use name_map. Do you know any other method which can reach my purpose?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If a name is `Anderson` then what would be the condition to rename it? How would we decide to rename it to "Rose" or "Gina"? Also can you please update the question?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. My purpose is to modify the "Name" to "Rose" in a01 and a02 , and "Gina" in b01 and b02. So whatever the name under "a path" or "b path", I need to modify them to "Rose" in "a path" and "Gina" in "b path".